# Issue in Exception with method overriding

Tags: java, exception, polymorphism, overriding

I have a below program:

```java
class SuperClassWas {
    void myM() throws NullPointerException{
        System.out.println("Super class myM called.");
    }
}

class SubClassWas extends SuperClassWas{
    void myM() throws RuntimeException{
        System.out.println("Sub class myM called.");
    }
}

public class MethodOveridingWithException {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperClassWas obj = new SubClassWas();
        obj.myM();
    }
}
```

As per the rule

> If SuperClass declares an exception, then the SubClass can only declare the child exceptions of the exception declared by the SuperClass, but not any other exception.

And in my program above super class method `myM` extends `NullPointerException` and subclass overridden method `myM` extends `RuntimeException` and when I try to run the program it works fine. Question is how why? Ideally it should not work because `RuntimeException` is not subclass of `NullPointerException`.

Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: where did you got that rule from? incomplete: 1) applies only to checked Exceptions; 2) it must be a child exception or the same exception type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This rule is true only for [checked exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1).

Here is a quote from [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> More precisely, suppose that B is a class or interface, and A is a
>   superclass or superinterface of B, and a method declaration n in B
>   overrides or hides a method declaration m in A. Then:
>
> If n has a throws clause that mentions any **checked** exception types,
>   then m must have a throws clause, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> For every **checked** exception type listed in the throws clause of n,
>   that same exception class or one of its supertypes must occur in the
>   erasure (§4.6) of the throws clause of m; otherwise, a compile-time
>   error occurs.
>
> If the unerased throws clause of m does not contain a supertype of
>   each exception type in the throws clause of n, a compile-time
>   unchecked warning occurs.

The exceptions in your question are unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is below

```
    If Subclass overriden method throws checked exception then superclass overridden method should throws supertypes of subclass exception or atleast same exception.
    If Subclass overriden method throws unchecked exception then superclass overridden method can throws any type of exception or no exception.         
    If Subclass overriden method throws no exception then superclass overridden method can throws any type of exception or no exception.
```